# Django not detecting language variations i.e. pt-br

Tags: django, localization, django-i18n

I am trying to add Spanish and English variations to my site. Specifically: `es-cl`, `es-pe`, `es-ar`, `pt-br`. However, once I generate the translations and compile them, it only loads the es and pt values, not the country-specific ones.

This is my config file

```
GLOBAL_LANGUAGES = [
    ('es', _('Español')),
    ('en', _('Inglés')),
    ('pt', _('Portugués'))
]

COUNTRY_LANGUAGES = [
    ('pt-br', _('Portugués (Brasil)')),
    ('es-cl', _('Español (Chile)')),
    ('es-ar', _('Español (Argentina)')),
    ('es-pe', _('Español (Perú)')),
]
LANGUAGES = GLOBAL_LANGUAGES + COUNTRY_LANGUAGES

# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#use-i18n
USE_I18N = True
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#use-l10n
USE_L10N = True
```

This is the data when I access these values from my templates, where I can see that the code is repeated for English languages.

```
{'BIDI': FALSE, 'CODE': 'ES', 'NAME': 'SPANISH', 'NAME_LOCAL': 'ESPAÑOL', 'NAME_TRANSLATED': 'ESPAÑOL'}
{'BIDI': FALSE, 'CODE': 'EN', 'NAME': 'ENGLISH', 'NAME_LOCAL': 'ENGLISH', 'NAME_TRANSLATED': 'ENGLISH'}
{'BIDI': FALSE, 'CODE': 'PT', 'NAME': 'PORTUGUESE', 'NAME_LOCAL': 'PORTUGUÊS', 'NAME_TRANSLATED': 'PORTUGUÊS'}
{'BIDI': FALSE, 'CODE': 'PT-BR', 'NAME': 'BRAZILIAN PORTUGUESE', 'NAME_LOCAL': 'PORTUGUÊS BRASILEIRO', 'NAME_TRANSLATED': 'PORTUGUÊS BRASILEIRO'}
{'BIDI': FALSE, 'CODE': 'ES', 'NAME': 'SPANISH', 'NAME_LOCAL': 'ESPAÑOL', 'NAME_TRANSLATED': 'ESPAÑOL'}
{'BIDI': FALSE, 'CODE': 'ES-AR', 'NAME': 'ARGENTINIAN SPANISH', 'NAME_LOCAL': 'ESPAÑOL DE ARGENTINA', 'NAME_TRANSLATED': 'ESPAÑOL (ARGENTINA)'}
{'BIDI': FALSE, 'CODE': 'ES', 'NAME': 'SPANISH', 'NAME_LOCAL': 'ESPAÑOL', 'NAME_TRANSLATED': 'ESPAÑOL'}
```

In the views, I'm checking that the language is activating successfully, but even if I try to access `pt-br` translations with `{% trans 'text' %}`, Django only loads `pt` value for that key. Same with Spanish.

How can I correctly load the locations for each of these countries? Thank you in advance for your help.